# css selector for all siblings with the same class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this situation:

```
<table class="tablemaster">
    <tr>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue" colspan="3">...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>

....

<table class="tablemaster">
    <tr>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
        <td class="propertyname">...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
        <td class="propertyvalue">...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have to apply a particular css property to the td with class "propertyname" only of the second table, i.e. only to the tds with class propertyname that have only siblings with that  class.
If i used .propertyname ˜ .propertyname i would select all elements but the first td, and i have to select all the elements of the second table.
Does it exist a way to obtain this goal without modifying the source code?
Either, is there a way to consider an element without children of a certain type? Because i could select all the td.propertyname of the .tablemaster tr that has no child of type .propertyvalue.
Thank you very mutch

Comment: Your question is confusing, not sure how the other user answered it in < 2 mins *(now deleted)* ..

Comment: I don't think you could do this with pure CSS, since you would need to know the nature of the child elements in advance before you select them, and this goes both ways (both for elements that have only siblings with the same class, and elements that can have other siblings).

Comment: Of course, selecting `.tablemaster:nth-child(2)` is just missing the point of the question entirely.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: The OP is asking how to select `.propertyname` only when all of the cells in the row have that same class.

Comment: @BoltClock anyways thats not possible

Answer (score -1):

As you say you want to select all td with class "propertyname" of second table then you can use this css code

```
<style>

.tablemaster:nth-child(2) td.propertyname
{
   background: #000;
}

</style>
```